# Compare json data receive from android to database data in php

Tags: php, json

I want to receive json data from android side.
The android side is sending username and password in json to this php side.
This is my php code:

```
public function actionGetUserLogin()
    {   
        // array for JSON response  
        $response = array();


         $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
         $user_login = "select * from user" ;
                     $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $user_login);

                     while($results = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
                            $user_name = $results['mobile_user_name'];
                            $pass = $results['mobile_user_pass'];
                            echo $user_name;
                            echo "</br>";
                            echo $pass;
                            echo "</br>";
                     }

        //compare the POST data from user with the existing username and     password in database table


if($_POST['username']==$user_name&&$_POST['username']!=""&&$_POST['password']==$pass&&$_POST['password']!="")
        {
            //if match with database record 
            $response["success"] = 1;  
            $response["message"] = "correct";
        }else{
            $response["success"] = 0;  
            $response["message"] = "wrong";
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

I get an error when i test out this method using this url: http://localhost/myproject/index.php/user/getuserlogin

**The error is : Undefined index: username**

**Is it something gone wrong with my php when accepting the json?
Is there a way to display the json data that was sent by android?**

Comment: You have to make sure that form use post method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionGetUserLogin()
    {
```

### Add this check before creating db connection

```
if(!isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']) || strlen($_POST['password'])*strlen($_POST['username'])==0){
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']. ' 401 Unauthorized');
return false;
}


        // array for JSON response  
        $response = array();
```

#### I suggest you to implement datasource connection as singleton

```
         $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
```

---

```
         $user_login = "select * from user" ;
                     $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $user_login);

                     while($results = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
                            $user_name = $results['mobile_user_name'];
                            $pass = $results['mobile_user_pass'];
                            echo $user_name;
                            echo "</br>";
                            echo $pass;
                            echo "</br>";
                     }

        //compare the POST data from user with the existing username and     password in database table
```

---

```
if($_POST['username']==$user_name&&$_POST['username']!=""&&$_POST['password']==$pass&&$_POST['password']!="")
            {
                //if match with database record 
                $response["success"] = 1;  
                $response["message"] = "correct";
            }else{
                $response["success"] = 0;  
                $response["message"] = "wrong";
            }

            echo json_encode($response);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```